# Column indicating count in Excel

Tags: excel

Let's say I have an Excel sheet with the following columns

```
Year ProjectName
2001 AAA
2001 MMM
2001 XXX
2002 CCC
2003 KKK
2003 NNN
```

I want to generate a new column indicating the total number of projects in that year:

```
Year ProjectName NumberOfProjects
2001 AAA         3
2001 MMM         3
2001 XXX         3
2002 CCC         1
2003 KKK         2
2003 NNN         2
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming your years are in column `A` with your header row in Row `1`, then stick this in C2: `=countif(A:A, A2)`. If you search your question's title in Google the first link that pops up has this exact solution.

Comment: Why aren't you using a pivot table for this? You can use `[year]` and `[ProjectName]` in `Rows` and again `[ProjectName]` in `Values`. This will group by `count` and you will have what you want.

Comment: agreed, use a pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns C and B, in column C add the following:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,A2)
```

(example for row 2, for other rows, change A2 as needed)